# Blender 2.80: Delete Collection or clear the intial scene in scripting mode

Tags: scripting, collections

The Python refernce says: `bpy.ops.outliner.collection_delete(hierarchy=True)` is the rightway to remove the collection and its contents, which are generated in every new document in Blender v2.80 (Beta).
But in Scripting Mode it says: `AttributeError: 'Screen' object has no attribute 'scene'`

How do I clear the initial scene and jump to the next point in my script?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the python reference re "_right way to remove collections_" and also provide the part of script that produces that error message.

Comment: There is no link, but if right click on the "Collection" item and hover above "Delete hierarchy" this Python command is shown in the pop up window. `bpy.ops.outliner.collection_delete(hierarchy=True)` is the part, where the error occurs. But the provided solution to _unlink_ the contents works perfectly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Unlink all children from the scene collection**

Not a fan of using outliner operators in scripts. Unlinking or removing the collections from a scene will also have the same effect of clearing a scene.

Script to unlink all the child collections from the scene's master collection.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

for c in scene.collection.children:
    scene.collection.children.unlink(c)
```

*Theoretically* could remove the child collections using `bpy.data.collections.remove(c)` above instead of unlink, however I found this has the tendency to seg fault my build of 2.8._ (See EDIT below)

Running this after removes the orphan collection

```
import bpy

for c in bpy.data.collections:
    if not c.users:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(c)
```

Similarly could remove the collections objects from blender file with

```
for o in c.objects:
    bpy.data.objects.remove(o)
```

EDIT. Update: removing collections from bpy data

```
import bpy

name = "Collection 1"
remove_collection_objects = True

coll = bpy.data.collections.get(name)

if coll:
    if remove_collection_objects:
        obs = [o for o in coll.objects if o.users == 1]
        while obs:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obs.pop())

    bpy.data.collections.remove(coll)
```

Comment: Is there a way once I remove the scene collections to also flush everything connected to them. Because I end up with orphan data, unused scenes, layers, objects, etc. which increase the memory usage.

Comment: Take out the users test. It's there as a failsafe since the collection is a user of the object. If the object is "used" as say a modifier target or somesuch then AFAIK this is another user and the object is not removed.

Comment: I have removed the users test but I still get orphan data for some reason.

Comment: I get the error:  "AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'scenes'" ..  researching..  the first times I tried this code it worked..

Comment: The closest above to getting that error is `context.scene` have you accidentally used `context.scenes`.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works but doesn't delete the sub collections from the `Orphan Data`,
Just incase someone wants a recursive solution:

```
import bpy

def del_collection(coll):
    for c in coll.children:
        del_collection(c)
    bpy.data.collections.remove(coll,do_unlink=True)

del_collection(bpy.data.collections["Collection_name_here"])
```