# Selecting a specific Collection by name and then deleting it

Tags: python

I have been referred to a link which has already answered this, however the script in the linked page removes all of my collections.
My collection is called "Animation". I am not currently working in this collection. So I am wanting to select this collection and delete it.
The script i was referred to deletes everything. Thanks for the help...

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

for c in scene.collection.children:
    scene.collection.children.unlink(c)
```

Comment: Please don't re-ask the same question multiple times, edit your original post and explain why the linked dupe doesn't solve your problem to re-open it. I think your other one was closed instantly because of its poor quality, a one-liner without showing any effort. Please take your time and read the help files, in this case: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions so we don't have to explain to you how this site works again and again. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Use Context**

> So I am wanting to select this collection and delete it.

Further to [Blender 2.80: Delete Collection or clear the intial scene in scripting mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130124/blender-2-80-delete-collection-or-clear-the-intial-scene-in-scripting-mode)

As is the case with most of blender making  active in the UI gives it context.

The context collection can be the scene collection so don't want to delete that.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

remove_collection_objects = True

coll = context.collection
scene = context.scene

if coll:
    if remove_collection_objects:
        obs = [o for o in coll.objects if o.users == 1]
        while obs:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obs.pop())

    if coll is not scene.collection:
        bpy.data.collections.remove(coll)
```

**Remove named collection and its unique objects**

Script below will remove the default scene collection "Collection 1" and all objects within it.

Change `name` to collection to remove and set the `remove_collection_objects` toggle.

```
import bpy
#from bpy import context


name = "Collection 1"
remove_collection_objects = True

#coll = context.collection # 
coll = bpy.data.collections.get(name)

if coll:
    if remove_collection_objects:
        obs = [o for o in coll.objects if o.users == 1]
        while obs:
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obs.pop())

    bpy.data.collections.remove(coll)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the collection directly with :

```
bpy.data.collections['Animation']
```

So you just have to :

```
import bpy

col_name = 'Animation'

try:
    bpy.data.collections.remove(bpy.data.collections[col_name])
except KeyError:  # Prevent failure if the collection doesn't exist
    print(f"The collection {col_name} doesn't exist")
```

[Source](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/130130/86891)

Comment: Agreed. I added a solution with a try/except for the sake of variety

Comment: AKA known as very pythonic  cant UV again..  See https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html#use-try-except-sparingly    Have found attachment to using `foo = collection["Bar"]` one of the commonest  reasons for confusing scripts given the nature of blenders naming system. Without a good remove regime, the object you think is "Cube" or modifier "Array" or ..,  may not be if another already has same name. , IMO good habit to not use addressing by name  (Apologies for being a stickler,)

Comment: @batFINGER Again, agreed, and as a matter of fact I prefer your proposal, I merely wanted to offer variety without too much complexity. However I think this kind of code optimisation is a bit out of context in this question since it is supposed to be a one-time operation. Cheers