# fully clear scene and cache from scene collections and their embeded components e.g. objects, meshes, materials etc

Tags: scripting, memory-management, cache

I have a script which I am loading mutliple .obj files of room models from the disk. Each .obj goes into sub-collections depending whether it is a room in the same house or not. In the beginning of the script I am trying to clear the previous collections. Βy doing that I thought that the corresponding embedded components are also deleted thus flushing the cache memory that they were preserving. But instead, I've noticed that this is not happening which ends up at some point to run out of memory, I learned that the hard way. What I've noticed is that I am ending up with a lot of orphan structures and so on.

Therefore, my question is whether there is a way to do that without resetting to factory settings, closing/re-opening the software or looping through all the objects, materials, meshes, etc in each collection as suggested in the link below and considering that I might have quite a few collections and sub-collections loaded each time.

The following links:

[How to completely remove all loaded data from Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46990/how-to-completely-remove-all-loaded-data-from-blender)

[Python: How to completely remove an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27234/python-how-to-completely-remove-an-object)

[Blender 2.80: Delete Collection or clear the intial scene in scripting mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130124/blender-2-80-delete-collection-or-clear-the-intial-scene-in-scripting-mode/130130?noredirect=1#comment328611_130130)

is what I've found from previous questions but one way or another they do not seem to work good enough or work at all. Thus, I would appreciate some feedback if possible, thanks.

The script that I am using which clears the collections but not their components is the following:

```
def clear_collections():     
    for c in bpy.context.scene.collection.children:
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.unlink(c)
    
    for c in bpy.data.collections:
#        if not c.users:        
        bpy.data.collections.remove(c)

def load_scenes(path):
    scenes_list = glob.glob(path)

    for i in range(len(scenes_list)):

        # find all the .obj files
        obj_files = glob.glob(scenes_list[i]+"*.obj")

        # create house collections
        scene_name = str(pathlib.PurePath(scenes_list[i]).name)           
        house_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name=scene_name) #create new collection in data
        bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(house_coll) #add new collection to the scene
            
        for j in range(len(obj_files)):
            print(obj_files[j])
            # get scene name and room and rename inline in blender
            room_name = str(pathlib.Path(obj_files[j]).stem)
            # create room collections
            if house_coll:
                
                room_coll = bpy.data.collections.new(name=room_name) #create new sub-collection in data
                house_coll.children.link(room_coll) #add new sub-collection to the scene
            
                # import scene with all objects not merged
                bpy.ops.import_scene.obj(filepath=obj_files[j], split_mode="ON", use_split_objects=True, use_split_groups=True)
                
                obs = [o for o in bpy.context.selected_objects
                    if o.type == 'MESH']
                    
                # put them in the center of the plane
                # TODO: find why model location is not changing as well
                coords = []
                for o in obs:
                    coords.extend(o.matrix_world @ Vector(b) for b in o.bound_box) 

                x, y, z = np.array(coords).reshape((-1, 3)).T

                global_xy_trans = Vector(
                    (
                        (x.min() + x.max()) / 2 , 
                        (y.min() + y.max()) / 2
                        )
                    )
    
                for o in obs:      
                    if o.parent in obs:
                        continue
                    o.matrix_world.translation.xy -= global_xy_trans
                # link objects to specific collection and unlink them from the root collection
                for ob in obs:                    
                    room_coll.objects.link(ob)
                    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.unlink(ob) 
                    
        # exclude from view layer
        bpy.context.layer_collection.children[scene_name].exclude = True   
    
    toggle_expand_collapse(2)

def toggle_expand_collapse(type = 2):
    # expand/collapse collections in outliner
    bpy.ops.wm.redraw_timer(type='DRAW_WIN', iterations=1)
    toggle_expand(bpy.context, type) # 1 for expand, 2 for collapse


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    # clear previous collections and their data
    clear_collections()
        
    # path to find scenecs
    path = "/home/ttsesm/datasets/houses/*/"    
    load_scenes(path)
```

Comment: How about `bpy.ops.outliner.orphans_purge()`?

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't seem to clear everything at once for some reason. Sometimes I need to call it multiple times to do that and moreover the memory consumption does not return back to the initial empty scene. For example I can notice that a brushes field remains there retained for a fake user or something, once I manually disable the retain and delete them then I can go back to the initial memory consumption.

Comment: Ok, I've put it in a `while` loop where it checks whether there are any data blocks remaining and if yes it purges them. It seems to work as long as there are not any data block marked as retained (which it should be like that). Apparently, by accident I have marked some brushes as retained in from my previous projects. Thanks.